Breakpoints not triggering in PyCharm while debugging Django application
I'm facing an issue with PyCharm where breakpoints in my Django application are not getting triggered during debugging sessions. I've tried setting breakpoints in various parts of my codebase, but none of them seem to work. I run the project in debug mode.
Could someone please advise on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? I'm specifically looking for tips or troubleshooting steps related to PyCharm's debugger in the context of Django development. Any insights would be highly appreciated!

Make sure you are not checking code coverage while debugging. The debugger and coverage easily get in each other's way.
